# php domdocument in one line

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm trying to create an one lined XML String using PHP programming language.

I'm using a DomDocument for that.

i'm setting `preserveWhitespace` to false and `formatOutput` to false but when i execute
`saveXML()` theoutput still shows me new lines betweeen each XML output. any ideas?

my code:

```
            $domtree = new \DOMDocument();

            $domtree->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $domtree->formatOutput = false;
            ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$dom    = new DOMDocument( '1.0' );
$dom->loadXML( '<nodes><test/></nodes>', LIBXML_NOBLANKS | LIBXML_COMPACT );
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput  = false;
// remove all new lines
$XmlFileText = preg_replace("/\n/", "", $dom->saveXML());
echo $XmlFileText;
```

Not the best way, but works. Hope it helps.